# How a method returns null as an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, resharper

Giving this TypeScript code:

```
interface MyInterface{
    myInterfaceProperty: string
}

class MyClass{
    myClassProperty: MyInterface

    myClassMethod(flag: boolean): MyInterface {
       if (flag)
           return null;

       myClassProperty = //...
       return myClassProperty;
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine but `ReSharper` is complaining about `return null;`:

> Can not covert type 'any' to type 'MyInterface'

What would be the proper way to return null interface?

Comment: Do you have strict null checks enabled? If yes, `null` is not `MyInterface` and you probably want `MyInterface | null`

Answer (score 6):

One problem is that Typescript counts both null and undefined as distinct types as opposed to the uninitialised state of the MyInterface object. You can find this mentioned and discussed further in the Typescript documentation: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#null-and-undefined).

You could change the type definition of myClassMethod to include null as one of it's possible return types which would look something like this:

```
myClassMethod(flag: boolean): MyInterface | null {
```

The error you listed does not seem to be the result of the null value however. It is more likely caused by the implementation of myClassMethod. Inside of your myClassMethod - at least in this example - you are not referencing this.myClassProperty ( an object implementing the MyInterface interface ) but are in fact creating a new variable which has no type and does not necessarily implement the required `myInterfaceProperty` property.

Changing this to `this.myClassProperty` would likely fix this error.